# iTerm2 zsh weird behavior

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

When I start an iTerm2 with zsh theme, it's going through some weird, sort of loading steps. When I open every new instance/tab it goes through different steps. It's listing them all at the top bar of the app. E.g.: zsh --> scutil --> ruby, sometimes it goes like zsh --> bash --> crun --> ruby... xcode-select... etc.
Here is an attached video illustrating a problem:
[Weird iTerm2 ZSH startup](https://monosnap.com/file/5SGb4xqHWycnTA6NQ83V3HAReDnGNB)

**Bashrc file**

```
export APB_HOME="/Applications/PrivateSign"
export APB_JAVA="/Applications/PrivateSign/java/Contents/Home/bin"
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
```

**Zshrc file**

````
export ZSH=/Users/yegorsteshenko/.oh-my-zsh
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
plugins=(
    git
    zsh-autosuggestions
    zsh-syntax-highlighting
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh```
````

Please advise how to fix this.

Comment: Can you paste your bashrc file here as well for debugging purposes ?

Comment: Sure, here is a .bashrc 

```export APB_HOME="/Applications/PrivateSign"
export APB_JAVA="/Applications/PrivateSign/java/Contents/Home/bin"
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"```

And here is a .zshrc
```export ZSH=/Users/yegorsteshenko/.oh-my-zsh
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
plugins=(
    git
    zsh-autosuggestions
    zsh-syntax-highlighting
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh```

Comment: I don't know that there is anything *to* fix. Your `.zshrc` apparently runs a lot of external commands, and your terminal is configured to show the currently running command in the title bar.

Comment: If you are running `zsh`, your `.bashrc` is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: yep, you're right @chepner. Not sure though, why it takes that much time to go through them.

Comment: Do you have plugins in `/Users/yegorsteshenko/.oh-my-zsh/custom`?